# how to export a table from codeigniter to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I need help to export table from codeigniter view and put it inside wordpress, if there an example i will be appreciated, because i trying with google but there is no good tutorial thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You want to be able to export a database table, from a CodeIgniter application to Wordpress?

Comment: both support mysql so there would be no changes i suppose !!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to export a 'view' into wordpress then all you need is an iframe to embed the page inside the other and point the href attribute at the codeigniter page.